# List of features available in different Common Lisp implementations

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Is there any reference available online that lists all(or almost all) the ANSI Common Lisp features implemented in different CL implementations. ie SBCL, CMUCL, CLISP, CCL, ABCL etc.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the implementations you list implement practically all of ANSI CL. The difference is more how it is implemented and what else they provide.

Comment: To clarify my question, this is the context I'm coming from: I'm trying to run some old CL code (which works partially) and was looking for a compatibility chart (something like those browser compatibility charts, eg. caniuse.com) for major current CL implementations.

Comment: If possible, it would likely be easier to help if you post specific features you're unsure about or errors you've gotten. [This](http://common-lisp.net/~dlw/LispSurvey.html) is the closest I'm aware of, though as @RainerJoswig said I wouldn't expect compatibility with the spec to be a big issue with the implementations you listed.

Comment: I agree that ANSI compliance is not likely to be an issue. It may help to know that you are likely to run into at least two other sorts of issues: pre-ANSI'isms, and implementation specific extensions. I'm not aware of a chart for extension compatibility -- nor even a push for extension compatibility at the implementation level. Typically when compatibility is required user level libraries which harness the implementation extensions are used.